# TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HtmlInputEvent'

Tags: javascript, angular, types, web-frontend

I am trying to upload a file but I get that error, help me please to compile.

Angular-----Error:

```
src/app/admin/producto/create-producto-dialog.html:38:47 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HtmlInputEvent'.
  Types of property 'target' are incompatible.
    Type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement & EventTarget'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement & EventTarget'.
        Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.

                         (change)="imgSelected($event)">
```

Code from component.ts

```
interface HtmlInputEvent extends Event{
  target : HTMLInputElement & EventTarget;
} 

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public file :File;
  public imgSelect : String | ArrayBuffer;

  imgSelected(event: HtmlInputEvent){
    if(event.target.files  && event.target.files[0]){
        this.file = <File>event.target.files[0];

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = e => this.imgSelect = reader.result as String;
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
    }
  }
}
```

Code from Html

```
<div class="text-center">
      <img alt="Chris Wood" [src]="imgSelect || '../../../../assets/img/default.jpg'" class="rounded-circle img-responsive mt-2" width="128" height="128">
      <div class="mt-2">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" required (change)="imgSelected($event)" type="file" style="width: 100% !important;">
      </div>>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please supply your code for `imgSelected` as well. Thanks.

Comment: the code is already there, thanks

Comment: Please include what you have tried already in your question. For example, if you've already tried to set `"strict": false` in your `tsconfig.json` you should let us know.

Comment: Hello, I am doing exactly the same as you, do you remember how you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Please read the error message:

```
Type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement & EventTarget'.
```

Your code is or may attempting to set `null` to an `HTMLInputElement` or `EventTarget`. Since `null` is not either one you need to update your `interface` so null values are allowed as well:

```
interface HtmlInputEvent extends Event {
  target: HTMLInputElement & EventTarget | null;
}
```

See [Unions and Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html)
 in the TypeScript Handbook for help.